# see values passed into a DLL?

Tags: windows, api, dll, com

Is there a way to see the values being passed into an API call to a DLL?

For instance, I was writing some code to simulate the user changing a computer name and adding it to a domain.

I was able to figure out how to do this using netapi32.dll NetJoinDomain and kernel32.dll's SetComputerNameEx but it took a bit me a while.

Is there a way to actually see the calls being made to particular DLL files? The parameters and functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An utility that may help you is [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645). It displays, in real time, all calls to the system DLLs and provides some data about its parameters. It's not the ultimate monitoring tool but it does a good job catching most calls with a lot of info for system calls at least.